# meaning of the following regular expressions written in perl

Tags: perl

Here is a piece of code

```
while($l=~/(\\\s*)$/) {
    statements;
}
```

`$l` contains a line of text taken form file, in effect this code is for go through lines in file.

Questions:

1. I don't clearly understand what the condition in `while` is doing. I think it is trying to match group of `\` followed by some number of white spaces at the end of line and loop should stop whenever a line ends with `\` and may be some white spaces. I am not sure of it.
2. I came across statement `$a ~= s/^(.*$)/$1/` . What I understand that `^` will force matching at the beginning of string, but in `(.*$)` would mean match all the characters at the end of string . Dose it mean that the statement is trying to find if any group of character at the end is same as group of character in the beginning of text ?

Comment: For a while I thought it was a `$1` (1st captured group) there which made the problem seem more complicated than it actually is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is interesting to note that this statement:

```
while ( $l =~ /(\\\s*)$/ ) {
```

Is an infinite loop unless `$l` is altered inside the loop so that the regex no longer matches. As has already been mentioned by others, this is what it matches:

- `( ... )` a capture group, captures string to `$1` (that's the number one, not lower case L)
- `\\` matches a literal backslash
- `\s*` matches 0 or more whitespace characters.
- `$` matches end of line with optional newline.

Since you do not have the `/g` modifier, this regex will not iterate through matches, it will simply check if there is a match, resetting the regex each iteration, thereby causing an endless loop.

The statement

```
$a ~= s/^(.*$)/$1/
```

Looks rather pointless. It captures a string of characters up until end of string, then replaces it with itself. The captured text is stored in `$1` and is simply replaced. The only marginally useful thing about this regex is that:

- It matches up until newline `\n`, and nothing further, which may be of some use to a parser. A period `.` matches any character except newline, unless the `/s` modifier is present on the regex.
- It captures the line in `$1` for future use. However, a simple `/^(.*$)/` would do the same.

Answer (score 1):

**1**. the *while*

Usually `while (regex)` is used with the `/g` modifier, otherwise, if it matches, you get an infinite loop (unless you exit the loop, like using `last`).
*statements* would be executed continuously in an infinite loop.

In your case, adding the `g`

```
while($l=~/(\\\s*)$/g)
```

will have the *while* make only one loop, due to the `$` - making a match unique (whatever matches up to the end of string is unique, as `$` marks the end, and there is nothing after...).

**2**. `$a ~= s/^(.*$)/$1/`

This is a *substitution*. If the string `^.*$` matches (and it will, since `^.*$` matches (almost, see comment) anything) it is replaced with...  `$1` or what's inside the `()`, ie itself, since the match occurs from 1st char to the end of string

- `^` means beginning of string
- `(.*)` means all chars
- `$` end of string

so that will replace `$a` with itself - probably not what you want.

Comment: `^.*$` does not match anything. It does not match a string with two newlines.

Answer (score 0):

it matches a literal backslash followed by 0 or more spaces followed by the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

it executes `statements` for all the lines in that text file that contain a `\`, followed by zero or more spaces ( `\s*` ), at the end of the line (`$`).

Answer (score 0):

`(\\\s*)$`  this regex means --- a `\` followed by zero or more number of `white space characters` which is followed by end of the line. Since you have your regex in `(...)`, you can extract what you matched using `$1`, if you need.

http://rubular.com/r/dtHtEPh5DX

EDIT -- based on your update

`$a ~= s/^(.$)/$1/` --- this is `search and replace`. So your regex matches a line which contains exactly one character (since you use `.`  http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html), except a new-line character. Since you use `(...)`, the character which matched the regex is extracted and stored in variable `a`

EDIT -- you changed your regex so here is the updated answer

`$a ~= s/^(.*$)/$1/` -- same as above except now it matches zero or more characters (except new-line)

Comment: thanks for answer. But why the extracted character will be stored in variable a , i thought the text in variable $a will contain the text after replacing the matching pattern with content of $1. Also i wanted to ask if the expression is checking if the character at end is same as character at beginning because of ^ .

Comment: @Gautam Yes, you are correct, but your matching pattern is everything in the line, so basically they are same. I am not sure what you mean by `character at end is same as character at beginning`. Your regex does not match for `^`, all it means the line begins with the something. Hope this clarifies your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

It matches lines that end with a backslash character, ignoring any trailing whitespace characters.

Ending a line with a backslash is used in some languages and data files to indicate that the line is being continued on the next line. So I suspect this is part of a parser that merges these continuation lines.

If you enter a regular expression at [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) and hover your mouse over the pieces, it displays the meaning of each piece in a tooltip.